# Multipolygon in Los Angeles County Parcels Tax Roll

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, well-known-text

I downloaded the Los Angeles Parcels Tax Roll data into QGIS. I copied the information for a single parcel results in QGIS:

`wkt_geom   OBJECTID_1  AIN Roll_Year   AssessorID  TaxRateArea TaxRateArea_CITY    SitusHouseNo    SitusFraction   SitusDirection  SitusStreet SitusUnit   SitusConcatenated   SitusCity   SitusZIP    SitusZIP5   UseCode UseCodeDescChar1    UseCodeDescChar2    UseCodeDescChar3    UseCodeDescChar4    totBuildingDataLines    YearBuilt   EffectiveYearBuilt  SQFTmain    Bedrooms    Bathrooms   Units   RecordingDate   Roll_LandValue  Roll_LandBaseYear   Roll_ImpValue   Roll_ImpBaseYear    Roll_totLandImp Roll_PersPropValue  Roll_FixtureValue   Roll_HomeOwnersExemp    ExemptionClaimKey   ExemptionType   ExemptionFullOrPartial  Roll_RealEstateExemp    Roll_PersPropExemp  Roll_FixtureExemp   netTaxableValue__Land_Imp_REX_HOX_  totBoundaryDescLines    BoundaryDescLine1   BoundaryDescLine2   BoundaryDescLine3   BoundaryDescLine4   BoundaryDescLine5   BoundaryDescLastLine    ParcelClassification    AdministrativeRegion    CENTER_LAT  CENTER_LON  Shape_Length    Shape_Area
MultiPolygon (((
6445171.31999936699867249 1754319.45000045001506805
6445165.38999937474727631 1754259.7400003969669342
6445040.50999936461448669 1754272.15000040829181671
6445043.06999936699867249 1754297.81000044941902161
6445046.4499993622303009 1754331.86000040173530579
6445171.31999936699867249 1754319.45000045001506805
))) 539190  7514021016  2014    7514-021-016    9359    TORRANCE    249         PASEO DE LAS DELICIAS       249 PASEO DE LAS DELICIAS   TORRANCE CA 90277-6439  90277   0100    Residential Single Family Residence Unused or Unknown Code (No Meaning)     1   1948    1948    1456    3   2   1   19900220    70378   1975    34771   1975    105149  0   0   7000                0   0   0   98149   1   TRACT # 10302 LOT   16 BLK    N                         14  33.81230373 -118.38371317   370.98874200978423  7529.721003203928`

What are the units of the multipolygon? My QGIS is set to EPSG: 3857. Although I think the units for the MultiPolygon are the same no matter what CRS is used.

And then how do I get just this parcel into QGIS. The database is rather large and I don't need it all.

Comment: 1) The CRS wasn't indicated when you downloaded the file ?
2) Filtering a csv is quite a common task (in qgis or in a spreadsheet) : what would be your criteria ?

Comment: @snaileater. They <https://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/2017/12/12/assessor-parcels-2016-tax-roll/> don't say, but much of the data is in EPSG: 2229. The download links states "ESRI file geodatabase" and the downloaded folder is "Parcels_2016.gdb." All of the real estate entities for Los Angeles County are in the file. When you load it into QGIS and info click on one parcel the "identify results" are those shown in original posting. But this comes up the same no matter what the projection used is. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: You say "i dont need it all" : i suppose you just want _a subset_ of the initial dataset ? How do u intend to filter those datas ?

Comment: All I want is to get the single parcel boundary into QGIS  `MultiPolygon (((
6445171.31999936699867249 1754319.45000045001506805
6445165.38999937474727631 1754259.7400003969669342
6445040.50999936461448669 1754272.15000040829181671
6445043.06999936699867249 1754297.81000044941902161
6445046.4499993622303009 1754331.86000040173530579
6445171.31999936699867249 1754319.45000045001506805
)))` and read the coordinates in units I can understand, e.g., EPSG: 4326.

Comment: I should add that although the information is marked MultiPolygon (I assume for their general case), the data I'm interested in is just a Polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you've correctly identified the CRS of this data as EPSG:2229.

1. Import the CSV into QGIS in its native CRS, EPSG:2229.
2. Select the one parcel you want to keep.
3. Export that parcel by right-clicking on the layer name > Export > Save selected features as...

   [image]
4. Save it in the CRS you want (eg, EPSG: 4326).
5. QGIS has many tools you can use to extract the geometric data you want. Eg, you can get the polygon vertex coordinates by using the Field Calculator to add a long text field with the `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` function.

Comment: Thank you. Most critical was 2. Selecting the parcel. I thought I had been doing that with Info, but then you lead me to look further: Edit > Select > Select Feature. I exported as geojson since it's easy to read. But I don't understand why "geometry" isn't shown as an export field although there is a section for geometry in the window that appears, so guess that's it. And exporting automatically puts in the selection as a layer which is nice. I'll look at 5 which might be more to the point. But now I have the individual parcel which loads much faster than all of them.

Comment: That's standard convention for how mapping programs handle geospatial data. The geometry is displayed on map, so for most use-cases you don't need to see it as text. If you need it in WKT format you can always access it through the field calculator as I described. Or if you export it to CSV, the geometry will be stored in a column that you can see in Excel.